# Can a host application communicate with an executing workflow?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to have communication between an application host and a currently executing workflow that application has initiated?

The scenario I have is that a workflow will be initiated with some context ... and then go into a loop, waiting for something in that context to change.  The context change needs to come from the application itself - it would effectively update the context so that the while loop could then exit and the workflow could complete.

I found this old article here which looks like a solution, but it also looks like it's using deprecated classes and i'm not sure the functionality is supported any longer (in .NET 4.6 for example):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695719.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WorkflowApplication then you can pass objects into the workflow.

i.e `WorkflowApplication _workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(new workflowName, iDictionary)`

You can pass a ref variable into a workflow application via the IDictionary. Then you can change its value outside the workflow but check the value inside the workflow loop

Or pass a delegate to a method into a workflow application via the IDictionary then invoke the delegate inside the workflow loop and act on the return value.

Answer (score 0):

yes the way to achieve this is via [Messaging Activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/messaging-activities).

Messaging activities allow workflows to send and receive WCF messages. So you're able to communicate back and forth to your own WCF service from the executing workflow. Updating status or asking for approval to move further on in the WF.

The best example I have previously used is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-workflow-service-with-messaging-activities)